# Imagebutton multiple clicks

Tags: android, onclicklistener

```
private Bundle detailsbundle = new Bundle();
private onFABCLick mlistener;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false);
    TextView naam = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView adres = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.adress);
    TextView gemeente = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.gemeente);
    TextView deelgemeente = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.deelgemeente);
    TextView postcode = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.postcode);
    final ImageButton favourite = (ImageButton)  view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    naam.setText(detailsbundle.getString(DETAILS_NAAM));
    adres.setText(detailsbundle.getString(DETAILS_ADRES));
    gemeente.setText(detailsbundle.getString(DETAILS_GEMEENTE));
    deelgemeente.setText(detailsbundle.getString(DETAILS_DEELGEMEENTE));
    postcode.setText(detailsbundle.getString(DETAILS_POSTCODE));
    boolean isFavourite = detailsbundle.getBoolean(DETAILS_FAVOURITE);
    if(isFavourite){
        favourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_black_18dp);
        favourite.setTag(R.drawable.ic_star_black_18dp);
    }
    else{
        favourite.setTag(R.drawable.ic_star_border_black_18dp);
    }
    favourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mlistener.onFavClick(favourite);
        }

    });
    return view;

}


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof onFABCLick) {
        mlistener = (onFABCLick) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement interface");
    }

}


public interface onFABCLick{
    public void onFavClick(ImageButton favourite);
}
```

In my activity:

```
public void onFavClick(ImageButton favourite) {
    if ((Integer)favourite.getTag() == R.drawable.ic_star_border_black_18dp){
        favourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_black_18dp);
    }
    else{
        favourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_border_black_18dp);
    }
}
```

So basically what my code is supposed to do: if the button is clicked, and it's a favourite, it gets removed from database (still need to write that, but irrelevant) -> icon changes. And vice versa. However if someone were to change their minds, obviously it has to be undone without changing the page. However, my code isn't doing that, it's only possible to click the button once, the second time it won't do anything (working both ways for first click).

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On onFavClick, you have to change the Tag too, otherwise the Tag stays the same.

```
   public void onFavClick(ImageButton favourite) {
        if ((Integer)favourite.getTag() == R.drawable.ic_star_border_black_18dp){ 
            favourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_black_18dp);
            favourite.setTag(R.drawable.ic_star_black_18dp); }
     } else{ 
            favourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_star_border_black_18dp); 
             favourite.setTag(R.drawable.ic_star_border_black_18dp); }
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Implement this for your button clicks events:

```
private int _clicks = 0;
k = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);


    if(count == 1)
         //do whatever
    if(count == 2)
         //do whatever
    if(count == 3)
         //do whatever
}
});
```